# Show two Activities inside an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-view

I have two different Activities, and I want to show them both at the same time in another Activity. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905272/android-how-to-add-another-fragment-to-the-main-activity/24907156#24907156

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its not possible , You have to use `Fragments` to do so...

convert those two Activities to `Fragments` and create a `Activity` and place those `Fragments` in `Activity`.

Ref :

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible with `ActivityView` in android. There is no proper documentation that is available on the internet. but if you can check the android source code you can able to find the code related to `ActivityView`. Android is using the `ActivityView` for its car launcher applications.

check out below links:

[google implementation of ActivityView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityView.java)

you can find the `ActivityView.java` usage examples

[here](http://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-10.0.0_r29/xref/packages/apps/Car/Launcher/src/com/android/car/carlauncher/CarLauncher.java)

[and here](http://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-10.0.0_r29/xref/packages/apps/Car/Launcher/)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes there is a way** ! You cannot display 2 activity inside one, you have to use **fragments** !

> A fragment is an independent component which can be used by an activity. A fragment encapsulates functionality so that it is easier to reuse within activities and layouts.
>
> A fragment runs in the context of an activity, but has its own life cycle and typically its own user interface. It is also possible to define fragments without an user interface, i.e., headless fragments.
>
> Fragments can be dynamically or statically added to an activity.

You'll find the answers of all of your questions about fragments [on this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Hope it's been helpfull =)

Answer (score 0):

Fragments and FragmentActivity comes into play here. Make your two activities separately as two different fragments, And attach these two fragments into a FragmentActivity. So that in a single screen you can view two activites(Here its a fragment).

You can also try using ViewPager concept it may suits to your scenario.

Download the sample here,
 http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html